# Can iPhone Siri recognize most of native speakers' English as long as the sentence is simple enough?

Tags: pronunciation

I ask the above question because Siri doesn't recognize certain words even if I tried many times.

For example, I asked Siri the following question.

"What does the word vilify mean?"

She doesn't recognize the word vilify.
I'm wondering if my pronunciation is too bad or Siri has a problem in the voice recognition.

Comment: FWIW, Siri (or Google's voice typing, for that matter) can't recognize my speech in my first language 100% correctly either (but they're usually good enough, though sometimes I'll get results similar to those funny Autocorrect fails. :P). -- Hah! I got it right in my sixth attempt. Here are the results: *What does the word to be 5 million; What does the word really find me; What does the word vilify me; What does the word vilify me; What does the word vilify me; What does the word vilify mean*. More surprisingly, Google voice typing got it right the first time. :-)

Comment: It would be interesting to know @Makato Kato's first language, and also how Siri **did** answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about humans learning English, it is about Siri learning English.

Comment: @user3169 If Siri understands native English, it can be used for non-natives to practice English pronunciation.

Comment: @P.E.Dant I'm Japanese.
I tried again.
This time Siri recognized it as 
"What does the word vilified mean?"
It improved.
But I don't know whether I'm used to Siri or vice versa.

Comment: @user3169 Continued. The problem is to what extent Siri understands native English pronunciation. So I asked the question of this thread.

Comment: @user3169 I'm waiting for your reply. Since you voted to close this thread, I think I have a right to ask your opinion about my comments for you.

Comment: Siri is a machine. Machines don't need English. People have far more depth than that, and there is no shortage of them. And as I read your accepted answer, it is about how to use software. This might be a resource question at best.

Comment: @user3169 You have several misconceptions.

First off, as a Japanese living in Japan, it's very difficult or expensive to find a native English speaker who I can have a conversation with.

Secondly I don't think I can improve my English speaking skills by using Siri.
I just want to improve my pronunciation by using Siri if possible.

Thirdly, no, it's not a question asking how to use Siri. I accepted the answer because he answered the question correctly, that is Siri has a problem in the voice recognition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, tried it three times. First time it said "No music playing". Second and third it tried to call one of my contacts. So, I guess your pronunciation might not be the problem. It's Siri.

Here's a [list of commands](http://www.cnet.com/how-to/the-complete-list-of-siri-commands/) you can use with Siri. One of them is

> Define [word].

I tried

> Define vilify.

A couple of times, but it didn't work.

Comment: "Vilify" was recognized correctly on the first try. Even rushed or garbled pronunciations return the proper answer. `iPhone 6S iOS 9.3.2`

Comment: @P.E. Dant I tried "Define vilify". She recognized it on the first try, too. What about "What does the word vilify mean?"?

Comment: @MakotoKato Use the @ symbol to address a user. Also, I tried the voice command/diction with the Notes app, and it took about 7 tries before it wrote "what does vilify mean". It worked the first time for "define vilify".